# If $A$ is an invertible matrix, then the column span of $A$ equals $F^{n\times1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A\in\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ is invertible so $\mathbb{F}^{n \times 1}=\text{span}\{C_i(A)\mid1\leq i \leq n\}$

What does being invertible has to do with the column span (unlike any other matrix)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, $C_i(A)$ denotes the $i$th column vector of matrix $A$.

Now the statement $\Bbb F^{n\times 1}={\rm span}(C_1(A),\dots,C_n(A))$ means exactly that the vector function $x\mapsto A\cdot x$ is *surjective*, while the invertibility of $A$ is equivalent to the *bijectivity* of the same function.

Comment: Thanks, Is there other explanation other than Functiouns?

Comment: Yes. You can rewrite the second statement as 'the *rank* of $A$ is $n$', which must hold if $A$ is $n\times n$ invertible.